# MAUI: Persisting access to Nextcloud files via the file picker in connection with an iOS File Provider

Tags: maui, filepicker, fileprovider

I have currently the problem specially on iOS, that when I select a file through the [FilePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=ios), which is located in Nextcloud and integrated in the file manager through the file provider, I get a shared path to the file. The access is now possible to the file.

However, if I now save the path and want to access it when I restart the application, this is no longer possible. I ran this on a local device.

```
Access to the path'/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/File Provider Storage/abcd.../test.xyz' is denied.
```

I couldn't figure it out from the documentation at apple.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider

Is the selected file only temporarily accessible? How can I permanently access e.g. a file in nextcloud via FilePicker without implement a WebDAV client to the app and constantly kept up to date the selected file?

With Android, as far as I have read, a permanent copy of the file is created, and access to the file also works when the application is restarted. Here, however, there is the problem that the file is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

The permission checks and requests are automatically handled by .NET MAUI. But, when you use the FilePicker, you need to enable the iCloud capabilities.

For how to enable the capabilities, you could check the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/entitlements

Comment: I have added the authorisation. Access through the file picker is also possible correctly. However, if I save the path of the file and call it again with File.Read() at the next app start, I no longer have access.

Comment: When you make sure you have enabled capabilities, have you tried to require the additional configuration of the App IDs? For this step, no more details on Maui, you need to check the old docs.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/capabilities/?tabs=macos